# Database modeling tool

Tags: database, uml

Do you know a free tool to model databases in uml?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a SourceForge project for UML/ERD modeling of databases:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbuml/

Here is software that has a free community edition:

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've always found that UML poorly handled designing databases. Entity-Relationship Diagrams always seem to better describe a database.

I would check out Open System Architect (OSA) at http://www.codebydesign.com/

Answer (score 0):

UML class diagram is an object approach while data is not.
Omondo has done a try to use a database profile and synchronize the stereotypes with the java persistence annotations. It means that if you create a class diagram you also create java persistence in the code. You just need a good mapper to create your database later.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you could use a standard class diagram to model your database. I know it's not the same underlying philosophy but concepts in Extended ER models and in UML CD are quite similar.

True, if you want to explicitly model everying (like pks or unique identifiers) you´ll need to use a UML profile. However, if you are happy with using some conventions (like adding a surrogate pk for each table, deducing automatically the fks from the associations,...), then you can even skip the profile. For an example of this approach [read this](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2db-full-code-generation-sql-scripts-databases)